# Links in repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF on WordPress.

I have made a repeater field. Every fields work fine, except links.
The code below shows the name of URL, but the name has no link!

```
<?php if( have_rows('dl_box') ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php while( have_rows('dl_box') ): the_row(); 

        // vars
        $content = get_sub_field('dl_link_name');
        $link = get_sub_field('dl_url');

        ?>

        <li>
        <span class="link">
            <?php if( $link ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if( $link ): ?>
            </a>

            <?php endif; ?>
   <?php echo $content; ?>

    </span> 
        </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I think it because of this line

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">
```

but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the markup as follows.  You are attempting to access variables that haven't been declared, and the logic is out of sequence:

```
<li>
    <span class="link">
        <?php 
        // $link is the URL (from "dl_url")
        // If there is a URL, output an opening <a> tag
        if( $link ) {
            echo '<a href="' . $link . '">';
        }
        // $content is the name (from "dl_link_name")
        // always output the name
        echo $content;
        // If there is a URL, need to output the matching closing <a> tag
        if( $link ) {
            echo '</a>';
        }
    </span> 
</li>
```

Note:
I have learned to dislike markup / logic like that - it doesn't make a lot of sense.  I'd rather do something like this - it's simpler, easier to read, and more compact:

```
<li>
    <span class="link">
         <?php
         // if there is a url, output the ENTIRE link
         if ( $link ) {
             echo '<a href="' . $link . '">' . $content . '</a>';
         // otherwise just output the name
         } else {
             echo $content;
         } ?>
     </span>
 </li>
```